# Blazor WebAssembly GraphClientExtensions fails after upgrading Microsoft.Graph to version 5.0

Tags: asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, blazor-webassembly, microsoft-graph-sdks, .net-7.0

Blazor WebAssembly GraphClientExtensions fails after upgrading Microsoft.Graph to version 5.0

Framework:  Dot NET 7

Errors:

- The type or namespace name 'IAuthenticationProvider' could not be found
- The type or namespace name 'IHttpProvider' could not be found
- The type or namespace name 'ISerializer' could not be found

GraphClientExtensions Code:

```
    internal static class GraphClientExtensions
    {
        public static IServiceCollection AddGraphClient(
            this IServiceCollection services, params string[] scopes)
        {
            services.Configure<RemoteAuthenticationOptions<MsalProviderOptions>>(
                options =>
                {
                    foreach (var scope in scopes)
                    {
                        options.ProviderOptions.AdditionalScopesToConsent.Add(scope);
                    }
                });

            services.AddScoped<IAuthenticationProvider,
                NoOpGraphAuthenticationProvider>();
            services.AddScoped<IHttpProvider, HttpClientHttpProvider>(sp =>
                new HttpClientHttpProvider(new HttpClient()));
            services.AddScoped(sp =>
            {
                return new GraphServiceClient(
                    sp.GetRequiredService<IAuthenticationProvider>(),
                    sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpProvider>());
            });

            return services;
        }

        private class NoOpGraphAuthenticationProvider : IAuthenticationProvider
        {
            public NoOpGraphAuthenticationProvider(IAccessTokenProvider tokenProvider)
            {
                TokenProvider = tokenProvider;
            }

            public IAccessTokenProvider TokenProvider { get; }

            public async Task AuthenticateRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
            {
                var result = await TokenProvider.RequestAccessToken(
                    new AccessTokenRequestOptions()
                    {
                        Scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read" }
                    });

                if (result.TryGetToken(out var token))
                {
                    request.Headers.Authorization ??= new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
                        "Bearer", token.Value);
                }
            }
        }

        private class HttpClientHttpProvider : IHttpProvider
        {
            private readonly HttpClient http;

            public HttpClientHttpProvider(HttpClient http)
            {
                this.http = http;
            }

            public ISerializer Serializer { get; } = new Serializer();

            public TimeSpan OverallTimeout { get; set; } = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300);

            public void Dispose()
            {
            }

            public Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
            {
                return http.SendAsync(request);
            }

            public Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,
                HttpCompletionOption completionOption,
                CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                return http.SendAsync(request, completionOption, cancellationToken);
            }
        }
    }
```

Upgrading the below packages caused the error:

- Microsoft.Graph  from 4.54.0 to 5.0.0
- Microsoft.Graph.Core from 2.0.15 to 3.0.0

Comment: I haven't found the solution but I notice it come from it. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ji8w3.png    and https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpZl9.png

Comment: pls kindly take a try with my code snippet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just [attach a guide](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md) for migrating to V5 here.

==============================

First, the issue comes from the changes of the package. There's no `IHttpProvider` and `ISerializer` in `Microsoft.Graph V5.0`, and `IAuthenticationProvider` changed from `Microsoft.Graph.IAuthenticationProvider` to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.IAccessTokenProvider`.

To troubleshoot this issue, I think we need to first integrate AAD into blazor wsam app. We just need to create a new application with picking up the authentication.

[image]

Then we add the Graph SDK. But the tutorial in [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/graph-api?pivots=graph-sdk&view=aspnetcore-7.0) hasn't updated. Using code in screenshot below will had issue like what you mentioned.

[image]

Now the construction method for `GraphServiceClient` is like below:

```
public GraphServiceClient(IRequestAdapter requestAdapter, string baseUrl = null): base(InitializeRequestAdapterWithBaseUrl(requestAdapter,baseUrl))
{
    this.RequestAdapter = requestAdapter;
}

public GraphServiceClient(TokenCredential tokenCredential,IEnumerable<string> scopes = null,string baseUrl = null
    ):this(new Microsoft.Graph.Authentication.AzureIdentityAuthenticationProvider(tokenCredential, null, null,scopes?.ToArray() ?? Array.Empty<string>()), baseUrl)
{
}

public GraphServiceClient(IAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider,string baseUrl = null
    ): this(new BaseGraphRequestAdapter(authenticationProvider, graphClientOptions),baseUrl)
{
}

public GraphServiceClient(HttpClient httpClient, IAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = null,
    string baseUrl = null):this(new BaseGraphRequestAdapter(authenticationProvider ?? new AnonymousAuthenticationProvider(), graphClientOptions, httpClient: httpClient),baseUrl)
{
}
```

So we need to re-implement the `IAuthenticationProvider` so that we can use it to inject new version `GraphServiceClient`. And below is what I did and it worked for me.

In blazor webassembly, we can change to write code like this:

Program.cs:

```
using BlazorWsamNet7;
using BlazorWsamNet7.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;

var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });

var baseUrl = string.Join("/",
    builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph")["BaseUrl"],
    builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph")["Version"]);
var scopes = builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph:Scopes")
    .Get<List<string>>();
builder.Services.AddGraphClient(baseUrl, scopes);

builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
});

await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

Then `GraphClientExtensions`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication;
using Microsoft.Authentication.WebAssembly.Msal.Models;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Kiota.Abstractions;
using Microsoft.Kiota.Abstractions.Authentication;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

namespace BlazorWsamNet7.Data
{
    internal static class GraphClientExtensions
    {
        public static IServiceCollection AddGraphClient(
            this IServiceCollection services, string? baseUrl, List<string>? scopes)
        {
            services.Configure<RemoteAuthenticationOptions<MsalProviderOptions>>(
                options =>
                {
                    scopes?.ForEach((scope) =>
                    {
                        options.ProviderOptions.AdditionalScopesToConsent.Add(scope);
                    });
                });
            services.AddScoped<IAuthenticationProvider, GraphAuthenticationProvider>();
            services.AddScoped(sp =>
            {
                return new GraphServiceClient(
                    new HttpClient(),
                    sp.GetRequiredService<IAuthenticationProvider>(),
                    baseUrl);
            });
            return services;
        }

        private class GraphAuthenticationProvider : IAuthenticationProvider
        {
            private readonly IConfiguration config;

            public GraphAuthenticationProvider(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.IAccessTokenProvider tokenProvider,
                IConfiguration config)
            {
                TokenProvider = tokenProvider;
                this.config = config;
            }

            public Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.IAccessTokenProvider TokenProvider { get; }

            public async Task AuthenticateRequestAsync(RequestInformation request, Dictionary<string, object>? additionalAuthenticationContext = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
            {
                var result = await TokenProvider.RequestAccessToken(
                    new AccessTokenRequestOptions()
                    {
                        Scopes = config.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph:Scopes").Get<string[]>()
                    });

                if (result.TryGetToken(out var token))
                {
                    //request.Headers.Authorization ??= new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token.Value);
                    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer "+token.Value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`appsetting.json`:

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant_id",
    "ClientId": "aad_client_id",
    "ValidateAuthority": true
  },
  "MicrosoftGraph": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
    "Version": "v1.0",
    "Scopes": [
      "user.read"
    ]
  }
}
```

my View razor component:

```
@page "/profile"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication;
@using Microsoft.Graph;
@using Microsoft.Graph.Models;
@inject GraphServiceClient GraphClient
@attribute [Authorize]

<h3>UserProfile</h3>
@{
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Property</th>
                <th>Value</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
            <td> DisplayName </td>
            <td> @_user.DisplayName </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> UserPrincipalName </td>
            <td> @_user.UserPrincipalName </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
@code {
    protected User _user = new User();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            _user = await GraphClient.Me.GetAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Test result:

[image]
[image]